# Is there a way to search an array of cells for a specific value and return an array of all cells that contain that value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to search through a column of 200+ cells for ones that contain a specific number. I want to be able to write a formula that returns the array of all cells that contain that number, not just the first cell. The output should be a vertical column with one datapoint per cell.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Where have you run into issues?  Do you have a [mcve] of your code so far, with a *small* selection of obfuscated sample data?  Generally, "is there a way" / "can I" questions get answered with **"Yes"**, because this is not a Code Writing service.

Comment: And how would the output look?  Is it one value per cell in a vertical list? One value per cell in a horizontal list? All the values in one cell delimited?

Comment: @ScottCraner I would like the output as one value per cell in a vertical list

Comment: @Chronocidal I've added a picture of sample data. So I want to filter out all cells that don't contain the number 450 for example. I was able to return one specific cell using a VLOOKUP formula and a concatenation of the different strings within the cell. =VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE("C V9P    ",  BDP(Z16, "PX_LAST"), " Comdty"), Sheet2!A1:A208, 1, FALSE)

Comment: The data is being imported from Bloomberg

Comment: Why not just filter the data-copy-paste.

Comment: @ScottCraner Excellent point.  Or, after the Filter, use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to get the range for Values or Address